# View Javadoc while there is an error

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

Type e.g. the following in a java project in Eclipse:

```
File temp = File.createTempFile();
```

This will give an error:

```
The method createTempFile(String, String) in the type File is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

The problem is, while the error exists, I can't use F2 to view the Javadoc of the command, so fixing the command without knowing how it looks correct is a little bit difficult (Eclipse tells you (String, String), but not what these parameters mean!)

So, how can I view the documentation for this command, while there is an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the cursor immediately after the opening parenthesis and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. It will show you all the methods with the typed signature and the Javadoc of the selected method.